# Is "workflow" a word?

Tags: word-usage, is-it-a-word

I'm trying to reference a business process in which a document has to be approved by several different people before it is finalized. I want to be able to say things like:

> We've modified the **workflow** to include an additional step.

and

> The **workflow** currently requires approval by three people.

Merriam-Webster Unabridged does not have an entry for "workflow", but I see many people using it anyway. Is it a word or not? If so, is there a good dictionary definition of it?

Comment: Dictionaries lag usage, and terms from fast-changing areas like business and technology won't always be reflected. But then, maybe you just need to try different dictionaries. [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/business-english/workflow) has it, as do [MacMillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/workflow), [American Heritage](http://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=workflow), [Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/workflow?q=workflow), and so on.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4192/15358

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OED’s earliest citation is from 1950, but as two words. It is defined as

> in an office or industrial organization, the sequence of processes
>   through which a piece of work passes from initiation to completion.

Whether or not it is in any dictionary is not in itself an indication of whether or not it is a word.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, *workflow* is a word.

> Noun - The flow or amount of work to and from an office, department, or employee.

http://m.dictionary.com/d/?q=workflow

Comment: Given this answer, the question would seem to be valid and should perhaps be re-opened?

Comment: @HighlyIrregular, I agree that this question should be reopened and that this should be the accepted answer. Workflow (single word) now seems to be widely accepted as correct and appears in more than a handful of dictionaries. Microsoft's spellcheck raises no flags about the word, and Google asks: "Did you mean: workflow" when you search for "work flow."

Comment: Ngram as well: [workflow vs work flow vs work-flow](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=workflow%2Cwork+flow%2Cwork-flow&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cworkflow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwork%20flow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwork%20-%20flow%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I agree with @Barrie that a word's existence is more than a function of it simply appearing in a dictionary, but _workflow_ seems to be a word.

Comment: Late to the party, but workflow is now also included in OED online British/world English (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/workflow) and American English (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/workflow).

Comment: And I see that was also mentioned in a comment to the question 4 years ago. I'll be quiet now.